# Error:Settings can not be imported because environment variables cant be defined (Django logging)

Tags: python, django, logging

i started a django application, i need to use logging module to my application

This is the (LOGGING part) in setting.py, i didn't change anything in it.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

}

I have a file named categories.py in the same directory as models and this is the code of categories.py

```
import logging
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import Task
from models import Category
from models import Subcategory

 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def li():
    logger.error('Finished')


def categories(request):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('categories/view all categories & tasks.html', {'all_categories': all_categories},RequestContext(request))
```

and i have another file named myapl2.py in the same directory as models.py and this is the code

```
import logging
import categories


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log',format='%(message)s,%(asctime)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',level=logging.DEBUG)

    categories.li()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the cmd , when i cd to this directory and run myapl2.py I got an error,

it seems there is a problem when importing categories,

I got the following in the cmd:

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

Raise error:Settings can not be imported because environment variables cant be defined

Answer (score 0):

If you just did python myapl2.py this error is expected, please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module

Answer (score 0):

First things first: the handiest way to write such a stand-alone script is to use a [manage.py subcommand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Two comments regarding your code:

- In myapl2.py, you're setting up logging. Django does the same, using your LOGGING setting. Those two might bite each other.
- And (probably a copy/paste error): there's a space in front of categories.py's `logging = ...` line, which might also give you an error.

Comment: In the first comment, if i set the disable to true in settings.py then it's donna be right so do i have to make further changes

Comment: I'd personally remove your custom logging config and turn your script into a manage.py subcommand. That's the most sure-fire way to get it working correctly.